# Select only specific values from array

Tags: php, arrays, filter

How can I only get records which have **cost_measure == "Percent"** from this array and then iterate over those records only.

This is array I have:

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=8)
      'cno' => string 'C-01' (length=4)
      'cost_name' => string 'TroÅ¡ak prijevoz' (length=16)
      'cost_description' => string 'TroÅ¡ak prijevoza od Husvarne do K+N' (length=36)
      'cost_type' => string 'Transport' (length=9)
      'cost_measure' => string 'Percent' (length=7)
      'cost_amount' => string '0.50' (length=4)
      'cost_vcfc' => string 'Fixed cost' (length=10)
      'custom_cost' => int 0
  1 => 
    array (size=8)
      'cno' => string 'C-02' (length=4)
      'cost_name' => string 'Carina' (length=6)
      'cost_description' => string 'Carina na robu koja se uvozi van EU' (length=35)
      'cost_type' => string 'Customs' (length=7)
      'cost_measure' => string 'Percent' (length=7)
      'cost_amount' => string '0.00' (length=4)
      'cost_vcfc' => string 'Fixed cost' (length=10)
      'custom_cost' => int 0
  2 => 
    array (size=8)
      'cno' => string 'C-03' (length=4)
      'cost_name' => string 'Banka' (length=5)
      'cost_description' => string 'TroÅ¡kovi banke za obradu transakcija' (length=37)
      'cost_type' => string 'Bank' (length=4)
      'cost_measure' => string 'Percent' (length=7)
      'cost_amount' => string '0.15' (length=4)
      'cost_vcfc' => string 'Fixed cost' (length=10)
      'custom_cost' => int 0
  3 => 
    array (size=8)
      'cno' => string 'C-04' (length=4)
      'cost_name' => string 'PDV' (length=3)
      'cost_description' => string 'TroÅ¡ak poreza za drÅ¾avu' (length=25)
      'cost_type' => string 'VAT' (length=3)
      'cost_measure' => string 'Percent' (length=7)
      'cost_amount' => string '25.00' (length=5)
      'cost_vcfc' => string 'Fixed cost' (length=10)
      'custom_cost' => int 0
  4 => 
    array (size=8)
      'cno' => string 'C-06' (length=4)
      'cost_name' => string 'Test cost' (length=9)
      'cost_description' => string 'This one is to test the change' (length=30)
      'cost_type' => string 'Main' (length=4)
      'cost_measure' => string 'Absolute' (length=8)
      'cost_amount' => string '120.00' (length=6)
      'cost_vcfc' => string 'Fixed' (length=5)
      'custom_cost' => int 1
```

After I get records with cost_measure == "Percent" I need to add these percentage to $number. For example:

```
$number + cost_amount 0.50 %
$number + cost_amount 0.15 %
$number + cost_amount 25 %
```

Comment: do you want to display the string like in example?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you want(value or string).try this:

```
 $arr=array()//your array...
  $number=0;$numberText="";
    foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
      if(strcmp($value["cost_measure"],"Percent") == 0){
        $number = $number+$value["cost_amount"];
       $numberText.="cost_amount ".$value["cost_amount"]." %<br>";
    }
    }
echo $number;//total percentage added.
echo $numberText;//string with all the percentages
```

Comment: OK this is not working properly. It adds up 120% and it should add up 25%, 0.50% and 0.15% from array and each separatly like this: $number*0.50%, $number*0.15% and $number*25% Not summing.

Comment: OK, I see where the problem is. It's not getting only Percent it gets all $value["cost_measure"]. That's why it's getting too big. It's getting Absolute also. Something is wrong with if(strcmp($value["cost_measure"],"Percent") == 0){

Comment: OK, I've got it. Revorked you're code a little and it's right what I wanted! Thank you so much for you're help!